# Issues with Date Time in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Having some problems with adding Date Time to my project, i have a creation form that ask for the make, model, color, lisensePlate, and then Date Time.  i have the drop down box that ask the user to click the date and then enter the time the vehicle was created.  After entering a date ex(10.30.2017 3:00 PM) i get an error that says the date time was entered incorrectly.  My Razor Index.cshtml is reference a models folder i created to add a search bar that will search all the makes of a vehicle in the database, i am not sure if that is conflicting with the date time or not.  in my cars.cs model page i have date time written out like so

```
[Display(Name = "Date Time")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public int DateTime { get; set; }
```

After speaking with my classmate he suggested we take an auto generator date time approach, where when the user enters all the vehicle information, and hits the create box, it will auto-generate the date time in the details page of the vehicle, to show the time the vehicle was entered.  I am finding issues trying to do this too! :( any help would be great.  if i 'am not explaining this well enough please let me know!

Comment: Pretty sure... `10.30.2017 3:00 PM` is not a valid date when entered as that. Try just `10/30/2017` as your input and see if it takes in the correct date?

Comment: I am sorry i am used to entering 10.30.2017 for work purposes.  on localhost it is entered at 10/30/2017 3:00PM

Comment: your data type is integer. How you put datetime for it. Use DateTime instead of int

Comment: Thank you @PromodPiyatissa after tinkering with it and the migrations its working fine now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have: `public int DateTime { get; set; }` is a type of integer. Change it to `public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }`

Comment: Thank you!! after tinkering with the migrations, it works now! again thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Do you know a way I could put the date time in a loop so when the submit button is click it time stamps the data entry?

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure if I understand why you need a loop for that or if that would help what you are trying to do, so basically you want the current timestamp when submitted? All you need to do is when submitted you get the current timestamp like so: `var timestamp = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: So in the controller under the create action method, is this where the logic would go for it, or would it be coded in the Razor page itself?